Layoutlmv3 preparing data issue
I'm trying to follow along with a layoutlmv3 paper; however, I am using a public dataset of invoices so I could have a better understanding of how it uses layoutlmv3. At the data preparation section I keep running into a "KeyError: pixel_values" error, and whenever I try to remove the pixel_values column I get a "jpeg image file not recognized error". The specific paper I'm following is here. The specific dataset I'm using is "mathieu1256/FATURA2-invoices" and the specific model I'm using is "microsoft/Layoutlmv3-base" because I couldn't find the layoutlmv3-base-uncased version on hugging face and my program seems to believe it doesn't exist.
Below is my code, there shouldn't be anything too crazy since I'm simply testing out the code and getting it to work.

#creates the id for each label and creates a dictionary, setting it such that {"O": 0} and so on
id2label = ["A", "B", "C", "D", 
            "E", "F", "G",
            "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M",
            "NO"]

#Enumerates at 1, 1-13 for the ner_tags
label2id = {l:i for i, l in enumerate(id2label)}


#creating the processor and model
#selects the device, either "cuda": A graphics device on the GPU, or the cpu
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

processor = LayoutLMv3Processor.from_pretrained(
    "microsoft/layoutlmv3-base", apply_ocr=False
)

#this is also where you classify the number of labels you desire
model = LayoutLMv3ForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(
    "microsoft/layoutlmv3-base", num_labels=len(id2label)
)

model.to(device)


#preparing the data
def encode_training_example(examples):
    #references to columns within the dataset
    #bewary that img is like that because it's already opened, if it's a path you may want to use Image.open(path)
    #change img to path if they are path variables
    images = [img.convert("RGB") for img in examples['image']]
    word_labels = examples['ner_tags']
    boxes = examples['bboxes']
    tokens = examples['tokens']
    encoded_inputs = processor(
        images, tokens, word_labels=word_labels, boxes=boxes,
        padding="max_length", truncation=True
    )

    return encoded_inputs

training_features = Features({
    'image': Array3D(dtype="int64", shape=(3, 595, 841)),
    'input_ids': Sequence(feature=Value(dtype='int64')),
    'attention_mask': Sequence(Value(dtype='int64')),
    'token_type_ids': Sequence(Value(dtype='int64')),
    'bbox': Array2D(dtype="int64", shape=(8600, 5)),
    'labels': Sequence(ClassLabel(names=id2label)),
})

def training_dataloader_from_dataset(dataset):
    encoded_data = dataset.map(
        encode_training_example, batched=True, remove_columns=xdata_invoices_dataset['train'].column_names.append("pixel_values"),
        features=training_features
    )
    encoded_data.set_format(type='torch', device=device)
    dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(encoded_data, batch_size=5, shuffle=True)
    batch = next(iter(dataloader))

    return dataloader

#training the ai dataset
train_dataloader = training_dataloader_from_dataset(xdata_invoices_dataset['train'])

#validating the ai dataset
valid_dataloader = training_dataloader_from_dataset(xdata_invoices_dataset['test'])

this code raises a
Could not convert <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=595x841 at 0x2319F352690> with type JpegImageFile: was not a sequence or recognized null for conversion to list type
error
However if you remove ".append("pixel_values")" in the dataset.map() function within "def training_dataloeader_from_dataset(dataset)" it raises a "Key Error: 'pixel_values'" error.
I'm stumped I don't understand what the error is, the given paper doesn't seem to run into this error, and any leads I get are either not helpful or completely off topic. I would love to get some input on this because I'm genuinely lost!
